# How did scholarly education work in Song dynasty China?

Tags: education, medieval-china

In [Song dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_dynasty) China, the [Imperial Examinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_examination) were held to determine who would become the new government leaders to replace the older hereditary system of power. According to several sources, any Chinese man of good standing could take the test. How did the education prior to taking the examination take place? In addition, did members of lower classes actually have an opportunity to receive an education to prevent the rich from maintaining their high social standing?

I have looked into this problem on several sites before, (e.g. *[Wikipedia:ImperialExams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_examination)*) but I could not find any good information on it other than a basic format of the exam. How would test takers get their education to take the test and how did government officials ensure that it was fair for the poor? How early would they begin studying for the test?  How early would education typically begin? Would they study at a physical school/university or at home with a tutor?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: `how did government officials ensure that it was fair for the poor?` They didn't.

Comment: What is wrong with the information in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_examination)? "Wealthy families, especially from the merchant class, could opt into the system by educating their sons or purchasing degrees."

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace How early would education typically begin? Would they study at a physical school/university or at home with a tutor?

Comment: @Galactic - I've moved the comment into the question; I've noticed that questions where you have to read the comments get fewer answers, lower quality answers, etc.   Strong questions explicitly address what is missing from Wikipedia in the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not a scholar of the period, but my understanding is that like most institutions, the goal was to perpetrate the institution, rather than to serve any other goal. The educated elite trained the children of the educated elite, and thereby created a privileged class that excluded the poor.  I don't believe that there were universities; if you wanted to improve your chance of passing the exam and being a part of the privileged class, your family paid for a tutor, who would drill you in the classics.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Was there any reason why universities emerged later on in China compared to Europe? Universities already existed in Europe at that time.

Comment: I really don't know the answer to that - my Chinese history is weak. I _suspect_ it has to do with the fact that Western history is framed by conflict between church and state (Universities were originally religious), while China had no similar counterbalancing institution.  But I lack the education & training to test that hypothesis.